# Could this deferred execution scheme be any simpler?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I've created this scheme to preserve function calls until all the arguments are available. The `stub_op` classes will be replaced with classes that implement a `forward`-like mechanism that receives notifications when a forward is finished.

I wanted to have a way to set up a function call that turned into a forward that was complete as soon as the function's arguments were available.

So I came up with this. Could this be done more simply?

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

struct base_stub_op {
   typedef ::std::shared_ptr<base_stub_op> ptr_t;

   virtual ~base_stub_op() noexcept(true) = default;
};

template <typename ResultType>
struct stub_op : public base_stub_op {
   typedef base_stub_op::ptr_t base_ptr_t;
   typedef ::std::shared_ptr<stub_op<ResultType> > ptr_t;
   typedef ResultType result_type;

   virtual ResultType result() const { return ResultType(); }

   static ptr_t create() {
      return ::std::make_shared<stub_op<ResultType>>();
   }
};

template <typename ResultType>
struct stub_const_op : public stub_op<ResultType> {
   typedef ::std::shared_ptr<stub_const_op<ResultType> > ptr_t;
   typedef ResultType result_type;

   explicit stub_const_op(ResultType &&val)
        : val_(::std::move(val))
   { }
   explicit stub_const_op(const ResultType &val)
        : val_(val)
   { }

   ResultType result() const { return val_; }

   static ptr_t create(ResultType &&val) {
      return ::std::make_shared<stub_const_op<ResultType>>(::std::move(val));
   }
   static ptr_t create(const ResultType &val) {
      return ::std::make_shared<stub_const_op<ResultType>>(val);
   }

 private:
   const ResultType val_;
};

template <typename ResultType>
struct stub_func_op : public stub_op<ResultType> {
   typedef ::std::shared_ptr<stub_func_op<ResultType> > ptr_t;
   typedef ResultType result_type;
   typedef ::std::function<ResultType()> func_t;

   explicit stub_func_op(func_t &&func)
        : func_(::std::move(func))
   { }
   explicit stub_func_op(const func_t &func)
        : func_(func)
   { }
   virtual ~stub_func_op() noexcept(true) { }

   ResultType result() const { return func_(); }

   static ptr_t create(func_t &&func) {
      return ::std::make_shared<stub_func_op<ResultType>>(::std::move(func));
   }
   static ptr_t create(const func_t &func) {
      return ::std::make_shared<stub_func_op<ResultType>>(func);
   }

 private:
   const func_t func_;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_op_ptr {
 private:
   // Returns false_type, which has a ::value that is false.
   template <class AT>
   static constexpr std::false_type is_it_a_ptr(...);

   // Returns true_type (if enable_if allows it to exist).
   template <class AT>
   static constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
      ::std::is_same<
         AT,
         typename stub_op<typename AT::element_type::result_type>::ptr_t>::value,
      std::true_type>::type  // note the true_type return
   is_it_a_ptr(int); // no definition needed

 public:
   // do everything unevaluated
   static constexpr bool value = decltype(is_it_a_ptr<T>(0))::value;
};

template <typename T>
class transform_type
{
 public:
   static constexpr bool passthrough = is_op_ptr<T>::value;
   typedef typename ::std::conditional< passthrough,
                                        T,
                                        typename stub_op<T>::ptr_t>::type type;
   typedef T orig_type;
   typedef decltype(::std::declval<type>()->result()) base_type;

   transform_type(const type &o) : wrapped_(o) { }
   transform_type(type &&o) : wrapped_(o) { }

   template <typename U = T>
   typename ::std::enable_if< ::std::is_same<U, T>::value && passthrough,
                              orig_type>::type
   result() {
      return wrapped_;
   }
   template <typename U = T>
   typename ::std::enable_if< ::std::is_same<U, T>::value && !passthrough,
                              orig_type>::type
   result() {
      return wrapped_->result();
   }

 private:
   type wrapped_;
};

template <typename ResultType, typename FuncT, typename TupleT>
class suspended_call {
 public:
   explicit suspended_call(FuncT func, TupleT args)
        : func_(::std::move(func)), args_(::std::move(args))
   {
   }

   // This can only be called once and will alter the state of the object so it
   // cannot be called again.
   ResultType operator()() {
      typedef call_helper< ::std::tuple_size<TupleT>::value> helper_t;
      return ::std::move(helper_t::engage(func_, args_));
   }

 private:
   FuncT func_;
   TupleT args_;

   template <unsigned int N, unsigned int... I>
   struct call_helper {
      static ResultType engage(FuncT &func, TupleT &args) {
         return ::std::move(call_helper<N - 1, N - 1, I...>::engage(func, args));
      }
   };
   template <unsigned int... I>
   struct call_helper<0, I...> {
      static ResultType engage(FuncT &func, TupleT &args) {
         return ::std::move(func(::std::get<I>(args).result()...));
      }
   };
};

template <typename ResultType, typename... ArgTypes>
class deferred {
 public:
   typedef typename stub_op<ResultType>::ptr_t deferred_t;
   typedef ::std::function<ResultType(ArgTypes...)> wrapped_func_t;

   explicit deferred(const wrapped_func_t &func)
        : func_(func)
   {
   }

   deferred_t until(const typename transform_type<ArgTypes>::type &... args) {
      typedef ::std::tuple<transform_type<ArgTypes>...> argtuple_t;
      argtuple_t saved_args = ::std::make_tuple(args...);
      ::std::function<ResultType()> f{suspended_call<ResultType, wrapped_func_t, argtuple_t>(func_, ::std::move(saved_args))};
      return stub_func_op<ResultType>::create(f);
   }

 private:
   const wrapped_func_t func_;
};

template <typename ResultType, typename... ArgTypes>
deferred<ResultType, ArgTypes...>
defer(::std::function<ResultType(ArgTypes...)> func)
{
   return deferred<ResultType, ArgTypes...>(func);
}

template <typename ResultType, typename... ArgTypes>
deferred<ResultType, ArgTypes...>
defer(ResultType (*func)(ArgTypes...))
{
   ::std::function<ResultType(ArgTypes...)> f = func;
   return deferred<ResultType, ArgTypes...>(::std::move(f));
}
```

---

Example use:

```
#include <sparkles/make_operation.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using ::std::cerr;

int a_function()
{
   cerr << "In a_function.\n";
   return 5;
}

int a_function2(int arg)
{
   cerr << "In a_function(" << arg << ").\n";
   return arg;
}

int main()
{
   cerr << "Here 1\n";
   auto func1 = defer(a_function).until();
   cerr << "Here 2\n";
   auto func2 = defer(a_function2).until(func1);
   cerr << "Here 3\n";
   cerr << "func2->result() == " << func2->result() << '\n';
}
```

The thing that this is actually eventually going to become a part of is called [Sparkles](https://bitbucket.org/omnifarious/sparkles/overview), and it's GPLv3, so the source code is there.

Comment: Why out of my league. There are not that many C++ reviewers here (and fewer that I have seen have this kind of knowledge). You may want to try pinging somebody from this list to give you some help: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers

Comment: @LokiAstari: I've done a bit of that, mostly by poking <Lounge C++>, but I'll try some more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the very first and important question: **what problem you are trying to solve with this code?** Why do you think it's better than simple:

```
auto call_chain = []()
{
    return a_function2(a_function());
};
std::cerr << "result == " << call_chain() << std::endl;
```

your code doesn't allow to do smth in the middle of function calls -- i.e. smth like this:

- call `a_function()`
- do smth while results available
- when result ready, pass it to `a_function2()`
- do smth else
- wait/check for final result

so, personally I see no reason to use your code (at least in it's current state)...

anyway, some (not/less important) notes about your code:

- do not use `::std::smth` everywhere, `std::smth` quite enough
- put your code into your own namespace. put everything what is not a public API into `your_ns::details` namespace
- use `inline` for your template functions in a header to avoid 'function redeclaration' errors
- use `override` for `result()` in `stub_op` child classes
- why to use `shared_ptr`,  why not `unique_ptr`?
- rethink semantic of your service classes and disable all not required (undesirable) ctors/assign operators for them to avoid use cases that shouldn't work
- currently `defer()` function won't work w/ labmdas and any user provided functors. to implement it in a better way, define it as `template <typename Func>` and then you have to analyze that `Func` is a callable type (using `boost::function_types` or smth similar). cuz C++11 have no concepts, you may use `static_assert` with human readable message sayin that `defer` should be instantiated w/ callable types only...
- no need to override a function w/ `T&&`+`std::move` and `const T&` parameters. use `T&&` and `std::forward` instead.

Comment: The library this will be incorporated in has something called a `remote_operation` which puts a notification on an inter-thread queue when it's done. A `remote_operation` is a type of `operation`. The `stub_op` class in the code above is a stand-in for the more complex `operation` class. While I was working on this, I didn't want to have to deal with the complexity of that class. Also, see this SO question to explain my stylistic use of `::std` everywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661912/why-does-everybody-use-unanchored-namespace-declarations-i-e-std-not-std

Comment: +1 for the `inline` suggestion. Though most compilers nowadays emit 'weak' bindings for template expansions so there can be multiples with no complaints.

Comment: And I would like `defer` to work with any callable. My overload for `function<ResultType(ArgT...)>` is a poor attempt at making that happen.

Comment: I used `shared_ptr` because you might say something like `x = defer(...).until(foo); y = defer(...).until(foo);`. Poof, now you have two things depending on the same object's results. That object can't go away until both dependencies have fetched their results.

Comment: @Omnifarious what kind of notifications do you use? I think (strognly believe) that using `boost::signals2` or (possible queue of shared) future/promises (`std` or `boost`) it would be possible to do the job simple than your approach. btw, `boost` allows to wait on multiple futures, in contrast to `std`. anyway if you are talking about _notifications_ `boost::signals2` is a first thing cames into my mind...

Comment: @Omnifarious about `::std` vs `std` -- some ppl are just crazy: they do things that they shouldn't do, then they starts to fight w/ consequences of wrong decisions...

Comment: Well, yes, they do stupid things. But I liken using `::std` to a good habit that you should be following with all the namespaces you use. If you give special treatment to `::std` you will forget to do it with a namespace for which it really matters. But anyway, I don't want to argue over that. If you want to, feel free to comment on my SO question. :-)

Comment: @zuafi: Threads are expected to have a loop that works like this: `while (true) { wq.dequeue()(); }`. The notifications are functors that are executed in the context of the receiving thread.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at boost. I will take a look at the libraries you suggest to see if they do what I was looking to do.